# Why isnt my hover command going across the entire bar? The light blue should go across the entire bar instead of just that much

Tags: html, css, hover, navbar

Why isnt my hover going across the entire side bar? I need the sidebar hover to be able to go across the entire sidebar instead of just that little bit. How would I fix this?

```css
#main-container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#sidebar {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 3.7%;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #0E4D92;
}

#sidebar a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255);
  margin: 15px 30px 0 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
}

#sidebar a:hover {
  background-color: #73C2FB;
}

#content {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 85%;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-container">
  <div id="sidebar">
    <img src="img/LetterLogo.png" />
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="about.html">Order</a>
    <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
    <a href="#">History</a>
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the way you create the index of the `#sidebar a` - using `left: 30px` with `position: relative`. Remove both, and use `padding: 10px 10px 10px 40px;` instead. In this way, the background would start from the left edge, and text would still be indented inwards.

```css
#main-container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#sidebar {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 3.7%;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #0E4D92;
}

#sidebar a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 40px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255);
  margin: 15px 30px 0 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#sidebar a:hover {
  background-color: #73C2FB;
}

#content {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 85%;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-container">
  <div id="sidebar">
    <img src="img/LetterLogo.png" />
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="about.html">Order</a>
    <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
    <a href="#">History</a>
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```